# error on adding two table views in swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

[image]

I am using two tableviews to display datas. My coding is below. I received error like this [image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52q9L.png)]. I don't know how to solve this. Kindly help me. If I test with 1 table it is working fine. But, while using two table, this type of error is coming. Also, why I am receiving this error. Kindly check my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.country_table_view.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "countries")
        self.laws_table_view.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "laws")

        self.country_table_view.rowHeight = 60
        self.laws_table_view.rowHeight = 60

    }



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if(tableView == country_table_view)
    {
        return self.countries.count
    }
    else
    {
        return self.laws_title.count
    }

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == laws_table_view)
    {

        var cell_new = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("laws", forIndexPath: indexPath) as laws_TblVwCell

        cell_new.laws_label.text = laws_title[indexPath.row]


        return cell_new

    }

    else
    {            
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("countries", forIndexPath: indexPath) as country_TblVwCell

        cell.country_name_label.text = self.countries[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error indicates is that a casting operation `as` failed.

Double-check your storyboard and make sure that the classes and identifiers of the cells are correctly set:

- laws table should contain a cell with identifier "laws" and class "laws_TblVwCell"
- countries table should contain a cell with identifier "countries" and class "country_TblVwCell"

And, fwiw, for legibility, both those classes should be renamed to at least start with a capital letter.  Classes, structs, enums and other data type names should always start with a capital letter.  Variables (and fields) should always start with a  lower case letter.

Comment: hi david..!! But two tables are working when we load either one table. But, when we load two, I am getting this error.

Comment: Not sure then, all I know is what the error message says and a very incomplete code example.  Check the stack trace and see if you can figure out exactly which cast is failing, although there's only 2 options in the given code.

Comment: sure i ll double check..!! one more thing,, can you check this and explain me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325384/in-swift-dynamic-height-for-uitextview-in-uicollectionview